# How does downloads counted in ios Appstore

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, app-store, app-store-connect

If I re-install an app, will it be counted as a new download in ios Appstore ?? There show an iCloud sign. Is that shows download from my iCloud account ?? I have tried to check different guidelines in itunes and appstore and cannot find any answer. Please help . . . . . Thanks in advance

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about something other than programming.

Comment: @trojanfoe But its very important to know. I can't find any answer

Comment: That's doesn't mean it belongs here.

Comment: What is your concern? Reinstalling an app downloads from the App Store, not your iCloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will not be counted as a new download, because when you download the app the second time apple uses your appstore account id to keep track of what you have downloaded previously.